# Moveto element in IE10 with Selenium

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium

I am experiencing a problem with the Webdriver method moveto in IE10.
What I intend to do is scroll an item that is not currently visible and is located in an overflowed div.

HTML example:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 500px; width: 200px; overflow: auto;">
  <div id="first" style="height: 1000px; width: 200px; background-color: red;"></div>
  <div id="second" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: green;"></div>
</div>
```

In the example above I would like to use moveto on the #second element. This works just fine in firefox but not in IE10. I'm using WebDriverJs and Selenium 2.33.0.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to scroll to element

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,2000)", "");
```

to scroll down to element.

To scroll up do

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(2000,0)", "");
```

Comment: I considered this too, but I would rather do this without javascript. Isn't it supposed to work with moveto?